# SoapUI and problem with Groovy Convert date to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: groovy, soapui

I've used this to add days to date and then format date to yyyy-MM-dd. But since new SoapUI version, this no longer work.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

String myOrderDate(int nrOfDays){ 
    def date = new Date()
    def datePlus = date.clone()
    datePlus = datePlus + nrOfDays
    return datePlus.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
}
```

Instead I get stacktrace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.plus() is applicable for argument types: (Integer)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your project include a dependency on `groovy-dateutil`?

Comment: How do I include dependency on groovy-dateutil?

Comment: "How do I include dependency on groovy-dateutil?" - See the answer I left in this question. 
 You can see an example of expressing the dependency at https://github.com/jeffbrown/groovydate/blob/f1be0251c45e256bf780a1675b55b376fe0c2f34/lib/build.gradle#L36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`public Date plus(int days)`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#plus(int)):

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

String myOrderDate(int nrOfDays){ 
    def date = new Date()
    def datePlus = date.clone()
    datePlus = datePlus.plus(nrOfDays)
    return datePlus.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
}
```

And you can do it shorter:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

String myOrderDate(int nrOfDays){ 
    def date = new Date()
    return date.plus(nrOfDays).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
}
```

Since there is an issue with importing libraries, maybe you should stick with Java way. Try following code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
    
String myOrderDate(int nrOfDays){ 
        def date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(nrOfDays)
        return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(('YYYY-MM-dd')))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I try your method I still get error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.plus() is applicable for argument types: (Integer)

Comment: This may not work in recent versions of Groovy unless you add a dependency on `groovy-dateutil`.

Comment: @user3624378 I updated the answer. Check if the java way works.

Comment: Hi, I added one parentehis in your example. It works just fine :-) return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(('YYYY-MM-dd')));

Comment: I don't think you need to `def datePlus = date.clone()` before invoking `plus`.  `plus` doesn't mutate the date so `def datePlus = date.plus(nrOfDays)` should be fine without needing a clone.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have will work fine if you add a dependency on `groovy-dateutil`.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/groovydate.

At [lib/src/main/groovy/groovydate/Library.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/groovydate/blob/f1be0251c45e256bf780a1675b55b376fe0c2f34/lib/src/main/groovy/groovydate/Library.groovy) is your method copied and pasted as is.

```
package groovydate

class Library {
    String myOrderDate(int nrOfDays) {
        def date = new Date()
        def datePlus = date.clone()
        datePlus = datePlus + nrOfDays
        return datePlus.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    }
}
```

The test at [lib/src/test/groovy/groovydate/LibraryTest.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/groovydate/blob/f1be0251c45e256bf780a1675b55b376fe0c2f34/lib/src/test/groovy/groovydate/LibraryTest.groovy) passes:

```
package groovydate

import spock.lang.Specification

class LibraryTest extends Specification {
    def "test order date"() {
        given:
        def lib = new Library()

        when:
        lib.myOrderDate(4)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

That only works because of the dependency expressed at [lib/build.gradle#L36](https://github.com/jeffbrown/groovydate/blob/f1be0251c45e256bf780a1675b55b376fe0c2f34/lib/build.gradle#L36)

```
implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:3.0.9'
```

Without `dateutil`, the runtime will complain about the missing method because it isn't there without the missing dependency.

Comment: How do I include dependency on groovy-dateutil in my SoapUI Pro project (Ready API)?

Comment: "How do I include dependency on groovy-dateutil in my SoapUI Pro project" - You should post that as a question of its own, or update this question to get rid of the date stuff.  That is a wholly separate question.  Best of luck!